# What is the equivalent of SQL subquery in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Is there a way to combine two finds in MongoDB similar to the SQL subqueries?

What would be the equivalent of something like:

`SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE name = (SELECT name FROM TABLE2 WHERE surname = 'Smith');`

I need to get an uuid from one collection searching by email and then use it to filter in another. I would like if possible to make it with just one find instead of get the uuid, store it in a variable and then search second time using the variable...

Here are the two that I want combined somehow:

```
    db.getCollection('person').find({email:'perry.goodwin@yahoo.com'}).sort({_id:-1});

db.getCollection('case').find({applicantUuid:'4a17e96c-caf9-4d78-a853-73e190005c63'});
```

Comment: You can do that with an aggregation, with a `$lookup` stage followed by a `$match` stage.

Comment: I am sorry, but I am real newbie with Mongo.
My two searches are:

db.getCollection('person').find({email:'perry.goodwin@yahoo.com'}).sort({_id:-1});

From that one I get the uuid and use it in the second.

db.getCollection('case').find({applicantUuid:'4a17e96c-caf9-4d78-a853-73e190005c63'});

So how these two can be done with single

Comment: Usually it is a poor approach to migrate each Oracle table one-by-one to a collection in MongoDB. Typically these information will be stored in a single collection.

Comment: See this doc: [SQL to MongoDB Mapping  Chart](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/sql-comparison/).

Comment: No no, I am not migrating anything.
I just started working with Mongo for the first time. There is existing DB that I need to use in automated tests.
The example with SQL was just to show what I am trying to achieve with single search.
I don't have an option to change how collections are organized. I can just use them as they are.